# Understanding mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php, fetch

Is there a way to make the code below cleaner?
I wanted to access the rows of `$query4week` like this: `$query4week[0]`.
But `mysqli_query()` returns an Object on which I don't know how to access its particular rows. So, using `fetch_array` and a `for` loop I decided to create my own index.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM meals ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7";
$query4week = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
for ($i = 0; $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query4week, MYSQLI_ASSOC); $i++)
{
    $meal4week[$i] = $result['meal'];
}
```

I am still learning PHP and yet quite weak with OOP topics, please be patient :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query` returns you a resource which represents the query result. You need to use the `mysql_fetch_*` functions to iterate over the result row by row. So yes, you need some kind of loop, if you are interested in more than the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in this way

```
$i = 0; 
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query4week, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $meal4week[$i] = $result['meal'];
    $i++;
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a for loop if your fetching an associative array.

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4week, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $meal4week[$i] = $row['meal'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: If missed the ; the first time too after $i++,  badly copy&pasty ;)

Comment: @justacoder fixed ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I had gone back to fix quotes in my typing, no copy pasta here.

Comment: No more missing, just an add to your response ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are already some perfectly reasonable answers here, but this is a little long for a comment. If all you are creating is a numerically indexed array starting with index 0, you don't need to explicitly define the index.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query4week, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $meal4week[] = $row['meal'];
}
```

should work just fine. No `$i` necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer -  this is a good alternative and would surely make the code cleaner. But I think @ZeissS answer helps me most, as I wasn't sure if I am doing something over-complicated or if there is an other fetch function which does all that at once.

Comment: That makes sense, that answer is a better explanation. There actually is another fetch function which does it all at once ([`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)), but as noted in the linked doc, it is available for MySQL Native Driver Only.

Comment: Another option if you want a `fetch_all` is to use `pdo` rather than `mysqli`. But fetching in a while loop is a pretty minor thing to do, and depending on your result set, often a better option anyway.